# Give an example of a connected closed subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C $

Tags: general-topology

Give an example of a connected closed subset $C$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus C $ has infinitely many components.

---

can somebody help me please.thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Think of the lines dividing up an infinite checkerboard:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot\\ \hline
\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot\\ \hline\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot\\ \hline\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot\\ \hline\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot\\ \hline\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot\\ \hline\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot&\color{white}\cdot
\end{array}$$

Comment: It would be harder to make one that is also bounded.

Comment: did not understand.will you explain please.

Comment: @ayesha: Can you find a closed subset of the plane that looks like that collection of grid lines? HINT: What does $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb R$ look like?